# @oneToMany with @JoinTable have unique constraint in jpa?

Tags: mysql, oracle, hibernate, jpa, jpa-annotations

I have a two tables which are USER entity have

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name="user_roles")
private List<Role> roles;
```

Role Entity have User

```
@ManyToOne
private User user;
```

Desc of table user_role is

```
Name                     Null     
USER_RECORD_ID  NOT NULL NUMBER(19) 
ROLE_RECORD_ID NOT NULL NUMBER(19)
```

NOTE: A user can have multiple roles,and i have already created roles through script,have Id:10001,10002,10003 etc

In  user_role role table i am inserting one user 800001 with all the roles so the table looks like

```
USER_RECORD_ID  ROLE_RECORD_ID
800001          10001
800001          10002
800001          10003
800002          10001   ///This record will through me unique constraint error
```

So if i try to give a role to new user where role is predefined it throughs me this error

```
INSERT INTO USER_ROLE(USER_RECORD_ID,ROLE_RECORD_ID) VALUES(800002,10001)
```

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYSTEM.UK_LPLHY51JOJA1LP4465QK2E0AF) violated
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.

Comment: Seems like its a many -to-many ... Don't u need to have a role / user and user_role ?

Answer (score 4):

I think the error is caused by the use of `@ManyToOne`/`@OneToMany` while the relation you have is `@ManyToMany`. This is so because in the example you give the `USER_RECORD_ID` with the value `800001` has multiple `ROLE_RECORD_ID` and the `ROLE_RECORD_ID` with the value `10001`has multiple `USER_RECORD_ID`.

Therefore try using `@ManyToMany`instead, this should fix your problem.
Here is a reference in case you need it: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany

Answer (score 2):

You have setup your mappings incorrectly, as it seems you have intended to have a bidirectional relationship that uses a relation table but instead have setup two independent relationships.  The first, User.roles uses the relation table, but the otherside

```
@ManyToOne
private User user;
```

is telling JPA to setup a Role-User relation that uses a foreign key in the Role table.  This doesn't seem to be the source of your problem, but will cause you other issues and doesn't match what you are asking for- Your role can only reference a single User, yet you are asking for roles to be assigned multiple users. Try:

```
@ManyTooMany
@JoinTable(name="user_roles")
private List<Role> roles;
```

.. and in the Role entity:

```
@ManyTooMany(mappedby"roles")
private List<User> users;
```

Also make sure you drop the database schema and let JPA recreate the database using these new mappings.